# Google maps API V3 Over_Query_Limit

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am trying to display some markers (around 10 to 15) using a loop and display the directions(routes) between them.But while the code is executing, "Over_Query_Limit error" occurs and is displayed through an alert box on the web page.Map is displayed correctly but markers are not displayed.I think it is due to exceeding the request for DirectionsService and Google doesn't allow to do that.

But if in case someone wants to print the directions,is it really possible to do it like this and if yes,then what may be the possible ways to achieve it.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the absolute daily limit (which is measured as 625 per six hours), there is a rate limit as well.

One way around that is to chain your requests, only making the next when the previous one has completed. You *may* be able to use `setTimeout` and find an interval which works, but that may not be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

you can do 2500 directions request per day. Read this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Limits

To reduce number of request, you can put waypoints in yours request. If you need a marker in each waypoint, active stopover property of the waypoint